# How to clear LWC lightning-textarea in javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-textarea

I have an lwc with a simple form which includes a few checkboxes and two selects and one textarea.

My submit function does a callout, and then clears the inputs. The rest of the inputs are cleared, but my textarea will not clear. I set the js variable to empty, tried to capture via

```
this.template.querySelector('textarea').value
this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea').value
```

I've tried giving a name to the container, and accessing like that, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```javascript
this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea').value = '';
```

This should work, if you have one lightning-textarea. If you have several, it affects the first found.

But `querySelector` fell out of favour, recently. [Consider `lwc:ref`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-dom-work.html). Markup:

```html
<lightning-textarea name="foo" label="Enter some text" lwc:ref="textArea">
</lightning-textarea>
```

Javascript:

```javascript
this.refs.textArea.value = '';
```

This has the benefit of pointing out a specific element, like an ID of an element in plain Javascript.

In any case, why don't you use an explicit value for the textarea?
Markup:

```html
<lightning-textarea name="foo" label="Enter some text" value={myValue}>
</lightning-textarea>
```

Javascript:

```javascript
this.myValue = '';
```

The latter is the simplest one, or not?

Comment: None of the template.querySelectors worked. I tried with All, so that I could see what came back but nothing did. The refs worked, thank you!